# Alternative to database table joins while filtering data

Tags: mysql, database, join

We have a portal where member signup. The members than participate in topics, discussions, get rewards etc. I guess similar to stackoverflow or other forums. Each of our client can customise the portal. One of the customisable option is member profile fields.

Any number of profile fieldS can be added in a portal, as this is done by clients. More than 10 is not uncommon.

Problem is related to filtering members based on these profile fields. If I have many profile fields in portal and the filter has lots of criteria the database query just doesn't work in realtime. For e.g. if the below database query takes ***10.57 secs*** to complete with filter for 10 profile fields:

```
select count(*) from  portal_member pm  ,
   profile_field_choice_value cr0  ,
   profile_field_choice_value cr1  ,
   profile_field_choice_value cr2  ,
   profile_field_choice_value cr3  ,
   profile_field_choice_value cr4  ,
   profile_field_choice_value cr5  ,
   profile_field_choice_value cr6  ,
   profile_field_choice_value cr7  ,
   profile_field_choice_value cr8  ,
   profile_field_choice_value cr9  ,
   profile_field_choice_value cr10
 where pm.portal_id = 56  and pm.status  =  2  
 and (
    cr0.client_id = 2130 
    and cr0.portal_id = 56 
    and pm.id = cr0.portal_member_id
    and (cr0.custom_field_id = 2334  and  cr0.custom_field_choice_id in (289739 ) )
  and (cr1.client_id = 2130 
      and cr1.portal_id = 56 
      and pm.id = cr1.portal_member_id
      and ( cr1.custom_field_id = 2335  and  cr1.custom_field_choice_id in (290057 ) ) )
  and (cr2.client_id = 2130 
      and cr2.portal_id = 56 
      and pm.id = cr2.portal_member_id
      and ( cr2.custom_field_id = 2340  and  cr2.custom_field_choice_id in (288285 ) ) )
  and (cr3.client_id = 2130 
      and cr3.portal_id = 56 
      and pm.id = cr3.portal_member_id
      and ( cr3.custom_field_id = 5006  and  cr3.custom_field_choice_id in (301530 ) ) )
  and (cr4.client_id = 2130 
      and cr4.portal_id = 56 
      and pm.id = cr4.portal_member_id
      and ( cr4.custom_field_id = 5477  and  cr4.custom_field_choice_id in (302751 ) ) )
  and (cr5.client_id = 2130 
      and cr5.portal_id = 56 
      and pm.id = cr5.portal_member_id
      and ( cr5.custom_field_id = 2342  and  cr5.custom_field_choice_id in (288294 ) ) )
  and (cr6.client_id = 2130 
      and cr6.portal_id = 56 
      and pm.id = cr6.portal_member_id
      and ( cr6.custom_field_id = 2622  and  cr6.custom_field_choice_id in (289738 ) ) )
  and (cr7.client_id = 2130 
      and cr7.portal_id = 56
      and pm.id = cr7.portal_member_id
      and ( cr7.custom_field_id = 5478  and  cr7.custom_field_choice_id in (302756 ) ) )
  and (cr8.client_id = 2130 
      and cr8.portal_id = 56 
      and pm.id = cr8.portal_member_id
      and ( cr8.custom_field_id = 5479  and  cr8.custom_field_choice_id in (302764 ) ) )
  and (cr9.client_id = 2130 
      and cr9.portal_id = 56 
      and pm.id = cr9.portal_member_id
      and ( cr9.custom_field_id = 5480  and  cr9.custom_field_choice_id in (302771 ) ) )
  and (cr10.client_id = 2130 
      and cr10.portal_id = 56 
      and pm.id = cr10.portal_member_id
      and ( cr10.custom_field_id = 5481  and  cr10.custom_field_choice_id in (302792 ) ) ) 
  );
```

Below are the table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE `portal_member` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `portal_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `portal_id` (`portal_id`,`status`),
  KEY `id_portal_idx` (`id`,`portal_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22222 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

CREATE TABLE `profile_field_choice_value` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `portal_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `portal_member_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_field_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `custom_field_choice_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `t` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_history_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `client_id` (`client_id`,`portal_id`,`portal_member_id`),
  KEY `custom_field_idx` (`custom_field_id`),
  KEY `portal_idx` (`portal_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=111111 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

#### My question is:

1. Is there an alternative to database joins? For e.g. maybe I can process the data by a cron job or something and do filtering on that?
2. Am I missing something obvious and doing the joins incorrectly. And this can be easily solved in database only.

Any help is appreciated. Thank is advance! If you don't see a solution but can guide me in the right direction that would also be great. I don't mind reading some book or learn some tech if I have to.

#### Mysql EXPLAIN result:

```
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key                         | key_len                | ref                                                                      | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr9   | ref    | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | custom_field_idx | 5       | const                                                       |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pm    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,portal_id,id_portal_idx    | PRIMARY              | 4       | sa.cr9.portal_member_id                      |    1  | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr10  | ref    | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | custom_field_idx | 5       | const                                                      |    2 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr3   | ref    | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | custom_field_idx  | 5       | const                                                      |    3 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr5   | ref    | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | client_id                | 15      | const,const,sa.cr9.portal_member_id |    5 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr4   | ref    | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | client_id                | 15      | const,const,sa.cr9.portal_member_id |    5 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr7   | ref    | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | client_id                | 15      | const,const,sa.cr9.portal_member_id |    5 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr8   | ref    | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | client_id                | 15      | const,const,sa.cr9.portal_member_id |    5 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr6   | ref    | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | client_id                | 15      | const,const,sa.cr9.portal_member_id |    5 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr1   | ref    | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | client_id                | 15      | const,const,sa.cr9.portal_member_id |    5 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr2   | ref    | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | client_id                | 15      | const,const,sa.cr9.portal_member_id |    5 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr0   | ref    | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | client_id                | 15      | const,const,sa.cr9.portal_member_id |    5 | Using where |
```

#### UPDATE1:

Tried one more query using inner join which takes ***10.50 secs***:

```
select count(*) from  portal_member pm
 inner join profile_field_choice_value cr0
    on cr0.client_id = 2130
       and cr0.portal_id = 56
       and pm.id = cr0.portal_member_id
       and ( cr0.custom_field_id = 2334  and  cr0.custom_field_choice_id in (289739 ) )
 inner join profile_field_choice_value cr1
    on (cr1.client_id = 2130
        and cr1.portal_id = 56
        and pm.id = cr1.portal_member_id
        and ( cr1.custom_field_id = 2335  and  cr1.custom_field_choice_id in (290057 ) ) )
 inner join profile_field_choice_value cr2
    on (cr2.client_id = 2130
        and cr2.portal_id = 56
        and pm.id = cr2.portal_member_id
        and ( cr2.custom_field_id = 2340  and  cr2.custom_field_choice_id in (288285 ) ) )
 inner join profile_field_choice_value cr3
    on (cr3.client_id = 2130
        and cr3.portal_id = 56
        and pm.id = cr3.portal_member_id
        and ( cr3.custom_field_id = 5006  and  cr3.custom_field_choice_id in (301530 ) ) )
 inner join profile_field_choice_value cr4
    on (cr4.client_id = 2130
        and cr4.portal_id = 56
        and pm.id = cr4.portal_member_id
        and ( cr4.custom_field_id = 5477  and  cr4.custom_field_choice_id in (302751 ) ) )
 inner join profile_field_choice_value cr5
    on (cr5.client_id = 2130
        and cr5.portal_id = 56
        and pm.id = cr5.portal_member_id
        and ( cr5.custom_field_id = 2342  and  cr5.custom_field_choice_id in (288294 ) ) )
 inner join profile_field_choice_value cr6
    on (cr6.client_id = 2130
        and cr6.portal_id = 56
        and pm.id = cr6.portal_member_id
        and ( cr6.custom_field_id = 2622  and  cr6.custom_field_choice_id in (289738 ) ) )
 inner join profile_field_choice_value cr7
    on (cr7.client_id = 2130
        and cr7.portal_id = 56
        and pm.id = cr7.portal_member_id
        and ( cr7.custom_field_id = 5478  and  cr7.custom_field_choice_id in (302756 ) ) )
 inner join profile_field_choice_value cr8
    on (cr8.client_id = 2130
        and cr8.portal_id = 56
        and pm.id = cr8.portal_member_id
        and ( cr8.custom_field_id = 5479  and  cr8.custom_field_choice_id in (302764 ) ) )
 inner join profile_field_choice_value cr9
    on (cr9.client_id = 2130
        and cr9.portal_id = 56
        and pm.id = cr9.portal_member_id
        and ( cr9.custom_field_id = 5480  and  cr9.custom_field_choice_id in (302771 ) ) )
 inner join profile_field_choice_value cr10
    on (cr10.client_id = 2130
        and cr10.portal_id = 56
        and pm.id = cr10.portal_member_id
        and ( cr10.custom_field_id = 5481  and  cr10.custom_field_choice_id in (302792 ) ) )
 where  pm.portal_id = 56  and pm.status  =  2;
```

#### EXPLAIN result for above query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                     | key                       | key_len | ref                                                       | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr9   | ref       | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | custom_field_idx | 5       | const                                                     |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pm    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,portal_id,id_portal_idx       | PRIMARY             | 4       | sa.cr9.portal_member_id                      |    1 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr10  | ref       | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | custom_field_idx | 5       | const                                                     |    2 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr3   | ref       | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | custom_field_idx | 5       | const                                                      |    3 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr5   | ref       | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | client_id               | 15      | const,const,sa.cr9.portal_member_id |    5 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr4   | ref       | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | client_id               | 15      | const,const,sa.cr9.portal_member_id |    5 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr7   | ref       | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | client_id               | 15      | const,const,sa.cr9.portal_member_id |    5 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr8   | ref       | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | client_id               | 15      | const,const,sa.cr9.portal_member_id |    5 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr6   | ref       | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | client_id               | 15      | const,const,sa.cr9.portal_member_id |    5 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr1   | ref        | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | client_id               | 15      | const,const,sa.cr9.portal_member_id |    5 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr2   | ref       | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | client_id               | 15      | const,const,sa.cr9.portal_member_id |    5 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cr0   | ref       | client_id,custom_field_idx,portal_idx | client_id               | 15      | const,const,sa.cr9.portal_member_id |    5 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
```

#### Update 2:

I was able to find one of the query that client actually used. This query just never completes. The profile_field_choice_value table for this client has 280K rows. Below sql query is that our team tried using inner:

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT pm.id) 
FROM   portal_member_id pm 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr0  
               ON pm.id = cr0.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr0.custom_field_id = 3697 
                  AND cr0.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19588 ) 
                  AND cr0.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr0.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr1 
               ON pm.id = cr1.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr1.custom_field_id = 3706 
                  AND cr1.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19623 ) 
                  AND cr1.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr1.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr2 
               ON pm.id = cr2.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr2.custom_field_id = 3709 
                  AND cr2.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19646 ) 
                  AND cr2.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr2.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr3 
               ON pm.id = cr3.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr3.custom_field_id = 3711 
                  AND cr3.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19653 ) 
                  AND cr3.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr3.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr4 
               ON pm.id = cr4.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr4.custom_field_id = 3712 
                  AND cr4.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19659 ) 
                  AND cr4.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr4.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr5 
               ON pm.id = cr5.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr5.custom_field_id = 3713 
                  AND cr5.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19663 ) 
                  AND cr5.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr5.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr6 
               ON pm.id = cr6.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr6.custom_field_id = 3714 
                  AND cr6.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19667 ) 
                  AND cr6.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr6.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr7 
               ON pm.id = cr7.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr7.custom_field_id = 3715 
                  AND cr7.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19672 ) 
                  AND cr7.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr7.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr8 
               ON pm.id = cr8.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr8.custom_field_id = 3716 
                  AND cr8.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19678 ) 
                  AND cr8.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr8.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr9 
               ON pm.id = cr9.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr9.custom_field_id = 3720 
                  AND cr9.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19714 ) 
                  AND cr9.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr9.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr10 
               ON pm.id = cr10.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr10.custom_field_id = 3722 
                  AND cr10.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19744 ) 
                  AND cr10.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr10.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr11 
               ON pm.id = cr11.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr11.custom_field_id = 3725 
                  AND cr11.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19807 ) 
                  AND cr11.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr11.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr12 
               ON pm.id = cr12.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr12.custom_field_id = 3726 
                  AND cr12.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19816 ) 
                  AND cr12.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr12.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr13 
               ON pm.id = cr13.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr13.custom_field_id = 3638 
                  AND cr13.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19169 ) 
                  AND cr13.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr13.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr14 
               ON pm.id = cr14.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr14.custom_field_id = 3641 
                  AND cr14.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19190 ) 
                  AND cr14.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr14.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr15 
               ON pm.id = cr15.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr15.custom_field_id = 3685 
                  AND cr15.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19326 ) 
                  AND cr15.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr15.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr16 
               ON pm.id = cr16.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr16.custom_field_id = 3686 
                  AND cr16.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19329 ) 
                  AND cr16.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr16.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr17 
               ON pm.id = cr17.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr17.custom_field_id = 3687 
                  AND cr17.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19522 ) 
                  AND cr17.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr17.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr18 
               ON pm.id = cr18.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr18.custom_field_id = 3688 
                  AND cr18.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19528 ) 
                  AND cr18.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr1.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr19 
               ON pm.id = cr19.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr19.custom_field_id = 3690 
                  AND cr19.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19533, 19534 ) 
                  AND cr19.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr19.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr20 
               ON pm.id = cr20.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr20.custom_field_id = 3691 
                  AND cr20.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19541 ) 
                  AND cr20.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr20.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr21 
               ON pm.id = cr21.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr21.custom_field_id = 3692 
                  AND cr21.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19552 ) 
                  AND cr21.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr21.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr22 
               ON pm.id = cr22.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr22.custom_field_id = 3793 
                  AND cr22.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19561 ) 
                  AND cr22.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr22.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr23 
               ON pm.id = cr23.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr23.custom_field_id = 3794 
                  AND cr23.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19572 ) 
                  AND cr23.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr23.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr24 
               ON pm.id = cr24.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr24.custom_field_id = 3795 
                  AND cr24.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19581 ) 
                  AND cr24.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr24.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr25 
               ON pm.id = cr25.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr25.custom_field_id = 3702 
                  AND cr25.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19614 ) 
                  AND cr25.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr25.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr26 
               ON pm.id = cr26.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr26.custom_field_id = 3704 
                  AND cr26.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19616 ) 
                  AND cr26.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr26.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr27 
               ON pm.id = cr27.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr27.custom_field_id = 3705 
                  AND cr27.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19618 ) 
                  AND cr27.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr27.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr28 
               ON pm.id = cr28.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr28.custom_field_id = 3707 
                  AND cr28.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19630 ) 
                  AND cr28.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr28.client_id = 223 
       INNER JOIN profile_field_choice_value cr29 
               ON pm.id = cr29.portal_member_id_id 
                  AND cr29.custom_field_id = 3708 
                  AND cr29.custom_field_choice_id IN ( 19643 ) 
                  AND cr29.portal_id = 683 
                  AND cr29.client_id = 223 
WHERE  pm.portal_id = 683 
       AND pm.client_id = 223 
       AND pm.status = 2;
```

Comment: Why don't you create a database view for this kind of search? Your query will have way less joins and it doesn't need to create it everytime you search for simple criterias.

Comment: To be honest, I don't like the drupal-esque database schemes where you have essentially one table for every variable (or variable type). if your use case permits why not have some config table with portal_id as an apparent primary key and sensible fields for each variable. then you would only join with portal_member. anyway ... those joins should be alright, if you have the right indexes defined.

Comment: @Cataklysim If there are lots of joins but there is a small difference in criteria I will have to create a new view for that. I think it will be slow for few of our clients who have lots of data (more than 1 million). Thanks.

Comment: @Jakumi I am not sure if I understood that clearly. You mean storing the data in multiple columns in a single table? Can you please give an example for that. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show an EXPLAIN for this? It _shouldn't_ be terribly slow...

Comment: @anishbhanwala I assume "pfc1.id = 101" stands for "the attribute is color" and the "pfc1.choice_id in (1001)" is something like "blue" so every row is essentially like "color=blue" or "size=60", if you'd have a table with columns (portal_id, color, size, ...) , perhaps with a member_id or whatever, your table would be larger and worse to extend, but I would argue ... nicer. However, this only is useful, if the attributes don't change dramatically over time (and you "decide", which new attributes get added)

Comment: @anishbhanwala to alaborate on Neville Kuyt's comment: the right usage of indexes will help *extremely*, to bring down your query time to sub-seconds.

Comment: @Jakumi as you mentioned the fields are really dynamic and vary considerably for each portal. So that may be a problem

Comment: There are no joins in the SQL you've shown us - it's a cartesian product

Comment: @NevilleKuyt  I have added the result of EXPLAIN. But this result is from my local database (not production), so I am not sure if this will be very helpful. Also don't you guys think with too many profile fields indexing may not solve this issue. For e.g. one client was using criteria involving 25+ profile fields. Which results in 25+ joins.

Comment: The explain is for a different query than the original one. This doesn't make answering your question any easier...

Comment: Can you please post DDL, including the indexes? It looks like the most expensive part of your query isn't using a selective index.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt Let me see if I can get the DDL and EXPLAIN result from production database. That should give you a better idea.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt I have updated the DDL and EXPLAIN results. Is it even worth trying to optimise a query that has 25+ joins or should we look for an alternate solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EXPLAIN shows that your indexes do not cover the query. This means that for every filter field you add, the server has to do much more work; it also means that adding indexes that cover the query should speed up the index dramatically.

Database engines are really good at joins. The "relational" part in RDBMS is all about that; as long as your joins can use indexes, they can handle huge numbers of joins on massive data sets.

Try adding the following index:

```
create index filter on profile_field_choice_value 
 (portal_member_id_id, 
 custom_field_id, 
 custom_field_choice_id, 
 portal_id, 
 client_id );
```

Comment: I was under the impression that sql query optimisation will never solve this kind of issue where you have lots of joins (maybe 15+ joins).  From the comments and feedback I got, after posting this question, I realised that not every problem is same and you cannot generalise that large number of sql joins cannot solve this issue. After realising that I did R&D and used EXISTS clause which along with the indexing right columns solved the issue. Thanks Neville.